# Using implode and concatenate at end of SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an implode at the end of the query and code is working fine with the values directly passed but not if values received by `$_POST`. is this the correct way to use implode and concatenate at the end of the `SQL query. Syntax error` at the end of the line.

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE ".implode(' OR ',$searchTermBits)." ";
```

The above format is correct with the dynamic inputs passed.

```
<?php
$username    = "xxxx";
$password    = "xxxx";
$host        = "xxxx";
$database    = "xxxx";
$server      = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection  = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
$search      = $_POST["deskey"];
$search      = explode(" ", $search);
$commonwords = "a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc,in,on,are";
$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);
foreach ($search as $value)
{
  if (!in_array($value, $commonwords))
  {
    $query[] = $value;
  }
}

$query          = implode(" ", $query);
$searchTerms    = explode(" ", $query);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
{
  $term = trim($term);
  if (!empty($term))
  {
    $searchTermBits[] = "description LIKE '%$term%'";
  }
}

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE " . implode(' OR ', mysql_real_escape_string($searchTermBits)) . "";
$query   = mysql_query($myquery);
if (!$query)
{
  echo mysql_error();
  die;
}
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++)
{
  $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($server);
?>
```

Comment: can you add final query please ? like echo $myquery; ...

Comment: Syntax error means you have invalid PHP code. You have written you face such error, but you have not share the error itself. Share it to receive adequate help, since the only line you have given appears to be OK - you have either an error somewhere else in your code or the `$searchTermBits` are not escaped and contain invalid characters. Along with that consider that such implodes in SQL statements can lead to SQL Injections so proper escaping is a must for each item in such arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only use the field-values. You need the key of the field as well to get working MySQL from it:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE 0" 
foreach($searchTermBits as $key => $value){
  $myquery .= " OR $key = '$value'";
}
```

The `Where 0` is important for the case where `$searchTermBits` is empty. You will still get a valid SQL-statement, even though it won't return anything.

This does not include escaping and checking the user-input jet. I assume you did that yourself as it's not part of the question.

**EDIT:**

Asked in a coment: "can you specify what you can usually get from the $_POST string?"

`$_POST` usally is an array that consists of pairs of keys and values to those keys. In a case like this the key would probably be the field you want to search in and the value the tearm you want the field to be.

With an array like this:

```
$_POST = array(
  "name" => "muster",
  "place" => "LA"
);
```

Your SQL would end up like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE 0 OR name = 'muster' OR place = 'LA'
```

Comment: can you specify what you can usually get from the $_POST string

Comment: Added a part about the content of `$_POST`

Comment: Still i am getting check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$search = array("name" => "muster", "place" => "LA"); //$_POST['search'];

$searchTermBits = Array();
foreach($search as $key => $value){
    $searchTermBits[] = $key." = '".$value."'";
}

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM 'logins' WHERE ".implode(' OR ',$searchTermBits)." ";
echo $myquery;
```

the returned query is

```
SELECT * FROM 'logins' WHERE name = 'muster' OR place = 'LA'
```